LFS booting EFI in macbook pro 2014
I am trying to build linux from scratch (LFS)  as an educational project using the main LFS book version 12.1, however, whene i reach the bottable chapter, i found that i have to boot my LFS using EFI support because my main machine is macbook pro 2014, so i follwo the BLFS guide Using GRUB to Set Up the Boot Process with UEFI, and https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/12.1/postlfs/grub-efi.html;
whene i re-boot the machine i get

error disk 'hd0,2' not found

I fix it by using

set root=(hd1,gpt4)

The next problem is

/boot/vmlinuz-6.7.4-lfs-12.1 not found

i checked my boot file and found the file name exists under differnt name /boot/vmlinuz-6.7.4-lfs-12.1-systemd so i rename it to /boot/vmlinuz-6.7.4-lfs-12.1.
No whene i am booting again i get a black screen after selecting the lfs system from booting menu .
attached files

fdisk -l /dev/sda outputs

Device         Start       End  Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         40    409639   409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2     411648  17807359 17395712   8.3G Linux swap
/dev/sda3  488847608 490117143  1269536 619.9M Apple boot
/dev/sda4   19855360  81295359 61440000  29.3G Linux filesystem

linux kernel configuration file
grub.cfg file
any help!

The answer is to copy the x64 booting image file not the x86 after linux kernel compilation like this.
the old code

cp -iv arch/x86/boot/bzImage /boot/vmlinuz-6.7.4-lfs-12.1

the new code

cp -iv arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage /boot/vmlinuz-6.7.4-lfs-12.1

